# Pylance doesn't recognize attrs.field with converters

Tags: pylance, python-attrs

Pylance seems to recognize an attrs field as a function (rather than a variable) when the paramter `converter=` is specified. Am I doing right and how to correct it? (Python v3.8.13, Pylance
v2023.12.100)

```py
"""
Why does Pylance recognize Test.x as a function (rather than a variable)?

"""
from typing import Optional

from attrs import define, field


def asstr(a: Optional[str]) -> str:
    """Return '' if a is None."""
    return "" if a is None else a


@define
class Test:
    """Test class"""

    x: str = field(converter=asstr)

    def test(self):
        """???"""
        self.x # Pylance: (function) x: str
```

[Here's what Pylance displays!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttDii.png)

Answer (score 1):

For a temporary fix you might want to try rolling back your version of Pylance to `2023.6.30` which seems to be the latest version of Pylance where this wasn't a bug. This worked for me, but introduced other worse bugs so your millage may vary.

I've also raised it as a bug on the pylance GitHub [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5391).